# Sorting an arraylist with lambda function isn't working

Tags: java, sorting, oop, arraylist, lambda

I'm trying to use `.sort()` method with an `arraylist`.
My method `public void sortSurname()` should **sort alphabetically all the objects by their surname**, these objects are contained in an arraylist `ArrayList<Contact> contacts`.
Could someone please find the issue with this code?
Here is what I've written so far:
Contact class

```
package main;
public class Contact {
    private String name, surname, cellphone;
    private Genere genere;
    
    public Contact(String name, String surname, String cellphone){
        this.name=name;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.cellphone=cellphone;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}
```

Rubrica class

```
public class Rubrica {
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    
    public Rubrica(){
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void sortSurname(){
        contacts.sort((Contact c1, Contact c2) -> {
            c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
        });
    }

    public void addContact(Contact c1){
        contacts.add(c1);
    }
}
```

Main

```
package main;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contact c1 = new Contact("Paolo", "Groviera", "338");
    Contact c2 = new Contact("Paolo", "Groviera", "234");
    Contact c3 = new Contact("Lampa", "Dino", "234");
    Contact c4 = new Contact("Lampa", "Dina", "0234");
    
    Rubrica r = new Rubrica();
    r.addContact(c1);
    r.addContact(c2);
    r.addContact(c3);
    r.addContact(c4);

    r.sortSurname();
    System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

**Thank you for the help.**

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then **edit** your question. Currently it is *nicely* minimal, but also *completely* unreproducible.

Comment: I have a problem also for this, I wrote the code in italian. The pieces above are translated, so what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `{}` which is a block and requires a return. Try it like this:

```
contacts.sort((Contact c1, Contact c2) -> {
   return  c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
});
```

or forget the `{}` and just do

```
contacts.sort((Contact c1, Contact c2) -> 
    c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname()));
```

or use the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and pass a method reference.

```
contacts.sort(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getSurname));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the { }

```
public void sortSurname(){
    contacts.sort((Contact c1, Contact c2) -> 
        c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
    );
}
```